# SharePoint 2013 User Profile Service Application is not synchronizing

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, profile-sync

In SharePoint 2013 farm UPSA running with no error but after full or incremental synchronization number of user profiles doesn't change.

[image: UPSA SP 2013]

Here is the number of user profiles section in SharePoint 2010 farm

[image: UPSA SP2010]

What is wrong with SP2013?

Comment: Are you using FIM or ADI?

Answer (score 0):

In your SharePoint 2013 farm there are multiple domain or single domain?

If multiple domain then please check all domain is running as well as please check synchronization connection whichever used for synchronize users with AD.

In Synchronization connection, Please check have you select all users checkbox in connection or not in populate user section.

Comment: There is single domain at SharePoint 2013 farm. We upgraded farm from SP2010 to SP2013 recently After that I realized that UPSA not working properly. SP2010 farm works normal. Also I did not see any synchronization connection in SP2010. Do I really need synchronization connection??

Comment: Yes, You will need to add synchronization connection with your AD. so it can sync users in SharePoint from AD.

Below are the steps for synchronization Connection

1) **Go to Application Manager in CA(Central Admin)**
2) **Click on Manage Service Application**
3) ** Click On User Profile Synchronization Service Application**
4) **Click on "Configure Synchronization Connections " under Synchronization section.**
5) **Click on Add new connection**
6) **Add your Active Directory Detail**
7) **Now, Run full synchronization timer job**

Comment: Please follow below link for create connection.


http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/07/23/setting-user-profile-synchronization-service-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I configured connection for our two domain controllers but there are 117 profiles imported not 11320. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Have you select all users in "Containers" section in connection page?
Have you run full synchronization or incremental?